# Efficient way to compare if items in a list exist in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists:

```
list_1 = ['Denver Broncos',
 'Carolina Panthers',
 "Levi's Stadium in the San Francisco Bay Area at Santa Clara, California",
 'Carolina Panthers',
 'gold']

list_2 = [['Denver Broncos', 'Denver Broncos', 'Denver Broncos'],
 ['Carolina Panthers', 'Carolina Panthers', 'Carolina Panthers'],
 ['Santa Clara, California',
  "Levi's Stadium",
  "Levi's Stadium in the San Francisco Bay Area at Santa Clara, California."],
 ['Denver Broncos', 'Denver Broncos', 'Denver Broncos'],
 ['gold', 'gold', 'gold']]
```

Is there an efficient way to compare whether each item from `list_1` appears in the corresponding (based on its index) of `list_2`?

Currently I have it as a `for loop`:

```
score = 0
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    if list_1[i] in list_2[i]:
        score+=1

average_score = score/len(predicted_answers)
```

but my lists are huge and I run this multiple times with multiple lists. I was hoping there's a more efficient way (I have access to a GPU if it help)

Comment: At the very least, use sets for searching instead of lists

Comment: Are the lists sorted? If so you can use a binary search instead of `in`. Otherwise the best you can do is `O(n)` for checking an element exists in a list.

Comment: The lists are not sorted. Regarding sets, you mean convert `list_2` to a list of sets?

Comment: Easier to use `zip`, e.g. `score = sum(team in teams for team, teams in zip(list_1, list_2))`.  That's not any more efficient though.  Mureinik's suggestion to use sets helps if you have the choice of making these sets before you get them, but if you're only doing this iteration once, going through and converting them to sets first won't speed you up any.

Comment: @Samwise Got it. Yea I don't have the option to make them sets beforehand unfortunately. I'm not an expert, but it seems like something parallel processing can be used for (e.g., GPU). Not sure if this is applicable though

Comment: It could be, but I don't think it's possible to do much with it if you receive the data in the form of a massive list -- however long it takes you to iterate through the list, it's going to take you just as long to feed it into something else that would be able to iterate through it faster.  You need to work on whatever is providing you with this list upstream to have it provided to you in a form that makes more sense; if it's that big, it seems like it should be living in a queryable database rather than in memory.

Comment: @Samwise Alas. Thanks for the help, I'll try figuring out if I can modify the upstream part.

Comment: If the inner lists are small (as in your example) then calling `in` on them will be fast. What are the typical sizes?

Comment: @JohnColeman The inner sublists are always small: < 5

Comment: @Penguin In that case, converting them to sets wouldn't give you much of a speedup. It might even hurt with the overhead of computing a hash. You already have `O(1)` lookup. Samwises's suggestion of using `zip` should give some speedup over your index-based approach. Perhaps he they can make it an answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman Got it! Thanks. I'll switch for the `zip` approach for now

Comment: What about `score = sum(map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(list_1, list_2)))` without having to loop? it seems that could be possible. But please someone should correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can perform the search in parallel with something like `with Pool(processes=cpu_count()) as p: score = sum(p.map(is_in zip(list_1, list_2)))`  with `def is_in(x): return x[0] in x[1]` but the gain will be less than a small factor. Furthermore, copying the data from one process to the other take some non neglictable time. Note that because of the GIL, parallel computation with threads is not straightforward.